# Prove that a convex function is the lower upper bound of a sequence of linear functions.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> I wish to prove that if $f$ is a convex function on $(a,b)$ with $-\infty \le a < b \le +\infty$, then $f$ is the sup of all affine functions majorised by $f$.

In order to prove it, I tried to prove first that

> For every $a$ there esists an affine function $g_a$ such that:

1. $g_a(a) = f(a)$
2. for all $x$ in $(a,b)$, $g_a(x) \le f(x)$.
   For this, I used the definition of convexity, fixing two numbers $x$ and $y$ and writing
   $$ f(ty + (1-t)x) \le tf(x) +(1-t)f(y) = t[f(y) - f(x)] + f(x)$$
   to deduce that
   $$ \frac{f(ty + (1-t)x) - f(x)}{t} \le f(y) - f(x) $$
   And then, setting $ty + (1-t)x = t(y-x)+x = x + h$,
   $$ \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \le \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x} $$
   But then I get stuck, because the LHS of the previous inequality not necessarily converges to the derivative of $f$, for $f$ is not necessarily differentiable.

Is there any more efficient way to prove this theorem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110793/discussion-on-question-by-logos-prove-that-a-convex-function-is-the-lower-upper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result cannot hold. Suppose $f$ is defined on the reals.

If $a,b$ are affine functions and $a \le b$ then we must have $b-a$ is a constant since the only affine function that is bounded above is a constant.

Hence if $\phi_n$ is an increasing sequence of affine functions, we must have $\phi_n = \phi_1+c_n$ where $c_n $ is a non decreasing sequence.

Then we have $f = \phi_1 + \lim_n c_n$ which is either affine or $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, my typo in the question: I was meant to write "affine" for the sequence, and I wrote "linear". My apologies for the error.

Comment: copper.hat is not saying that the linearity is the problem, but that the sequence $\phi_n$ is increasing